# What is the best way to manual install an Azure VM Extension?

Tags: azure

I need to install a modified azure linux vm extension.
Unfortunately the documentation doesn't mention an easy way to install them.

Powershell, Azure CLI or Azure Portal would work.

Comment: What's extension do you want to install? Custom Script or others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PowerShell, Azure CLI or Azure Portal to configure VM Extension’s parameters. However, the VM Extension is installed by waagent, so you could find install logs in `/var/log/waagent.log`. If waagent does not install in your VM, you could not install VM Extension.

More information please refer to this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-extensions-features?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json#prerequisites).

Answer (score 0):

To install the agent, the best way is to install from your distributions pacakge repository all of the [supported distro providers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-endorsed-distros?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Flinux%2Ftoc.json) have this already available.
If you need to install from source then you can look [here](https://github.com/Azure/WALinuxAgent).